# Redis SCARD returning the wrong results?

Tags: php, redis, predis

I'm adding a large number of data points into a redis set:

```
$t = 0;
$redis = Redis::Connection();
foreach($adv as $a) {
    $t = $t + 1;
    print($t); //Prints to log

    $test = $redis -> sadd('database/ab/AL', $a -> id);
    print($test); //Prints to log
}
```

When I call `redis->scard('database/ab/AL')` I get the result `9832`, The answer I should be getting is `9866`

`$t` is a counter I put in to check how many iterations the loop is doing, and `$t` is `9866` after running the loop, which is weird considering scard is returning `9832`

Then I thought maybe there are duplicates being added, so I logged the response from `sadd`

```
1 [2015-06-29 16:24:55] local.INFO: 1 [] []
2 [2015-06-29 16:24:55] local.INFO: 1 [] []
3 [2015-06-29 16:24:55] local.INFO: 1 [] []
4 [2015-06-29 16:24:55] local.INFO: 1 [] []
5 [2015-06-29 16:24:55] local.INFO: 1 [] []
6 [2015-06-29 16:24:55] local.INFO: 1 [] []
...
9861 [2015-06-29 16:24:59] local.INFO: 1 [] []
9862 [2015-06-29 16:24:59] local.INFO: 1 [] []
9863 [2015-06-29 16:24:59] local.INFO: 1 [] []
9864 [2015-06-29 16:24:59] local.INFO: 1 [] []
9865 [2015-06-29 16:24:59] local.INFO: 1 [] []
9866 [2015-06-29 16:24:59] local.INFO: 1 [] []
```

There are no zeros in the entire log, which means that each element being added is unique. There are also `9866` log calls which contradicts the `scard` result.
I have tried checking with redis-cli and I still get the wrong results. 
What gives?

Comment: Did you log the `SADD` responses with pipelining commented out too? I'm almost positive that you have duplicates and that the count is right, but pipelining can mess with the responses in this case

Comment: Yes, these results were taken **without** pipelining. I removed the commented sections to avoid confusion. I'm certain that there are no duplicates(though I could be wrong). The data I'm iterating over, `$adv`, is from an SQL query with the `DISTINCT` modifier

Comment: Suggestion: before you run your code, run `MONITOR` in a different connection to your database. This will show you all the commands rushing in... capture that and it should be fairly simply to see where things went wrong from it.

Comment: Is this behaviour repeatable? Are you tried to drop set and fill it again? Get you same wrong result or other wrong result?

Comment: Yup, I have tried it over and over again with the same `9832` result. So far this is the only table that returns this. There are no duplicates in the table, but when I run the raw SQL query, there are indeed `9866` rows.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I ran `MONITOR` as you suggeste and there are `9866` entries, yet `SCARD` returns the wrong result

Comment: Did you dedup MONITOR's output as well or just wc?

Comment: @ItamarHaber 
turns out it was because some keys were lowercase than uppercase!

Comment: Pff.. Why you didn't include variable part to question?

Comment: LOL - at least we got a good measure of excitement :) Upvoting your answer!

Comment: @vp_arth I definitely should have, but I modified the code I posted for simplicity's sake. Next time I won't do that. I have two mistakes to learn from now :)

Comment: I'm just little angry :) I remove my downvotes. Yet another proof, that there are not miracles.

Comment: @vp_arth exactly... and sometimes it takes more than one pair of eyes and a single troubled soul to get to the right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I was actually keying the values with a variable:

`$redis->sadd('database/ab/state:'.$a->state, a->id);`

turns out some states were in lowercase, which sent those values to another key.

Fix: `$redis->sadd('database/ab/state:'.strtoupper($a->state), a->id);`

now I get the correct number, `9866`, when I call `SCARD`

Always double check your key names!

Comment: I broke my redis with huge amount of tests, but you just lied in the question. `Always provide actual code in the SO questions`